# Updating ol.layer.Tile parameters in OpenLayers 3.9.0

Tags: wms, openlayers, openlayers-2

I have a TileWMS:

```
var mapWMSTile = new ol.source.TileWMS(
            {
                url: '.....',
                params: {'LAYERS': 'l1,l2', VERSION: '1.3.0', 'TILED': true},
                serverType: 'mapserver'
            });

        var fieldTile = new ol.layer.Tile(
            {
                source: mapWMSTile,
                name: 'fieldTile'
            });
```

Now I want to add a layers to my WMS parameters (e.g. add l3 in 'LAYERS'). Is this possible?

I have tried the below codes without success:

First try:

```
mapWMSTile.updateParams(
                {
                    params: {'LAYERS': 'l3', VERSION: '1.3.0', 'TILED': true}
                });
```

Second try:

`fieldTile.getSource().updateParams({'LAYERS': 'l3', VERSION: '1.3.0', 'TILED': true});`

I am using OpenLayers 3.9.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mapWMSTile.updateParams({
    'LAYERS': 'l3',
    'VERSION': '1.3.0',
    'TILED': true
});
```

Comment: I can't believe that I was missing `'` in version.... Thank you

Comment: @MenelaosKotsollaris The main issue with your code was not the ', but that the params were wrapped in another object (like the source constructor options).

Comment: just noticed... that's what happens after 12h of programming.. ;/

Comment: by the way do you know any way of setting a specific bound to the view (e.g to show the map only between `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` ?

Comment: Check out the extent option of the view.

Comment: Any ideas why this doesn't work in OL4? I get `'updateParams' does not exist on type 'Source'`. I have to create a new WMStile source, then use `myTileLayer.setSource(newSource)` to get it working.